# Python 3, sys.path doesn't work, how to permenantly append a path?

Tags: python, linux, django, fedora

Firstly, I am using Fedora 20, Python3.3

Basically everytime I have to use any python libraries I have to use:

```
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/')
```

This is getting to be a real problem because trying to use other libraries that need other libraries also can't find the site-packages and it is a real hassle. 

I guess my main question is how do I fix this problem without having to do a complete wipe that would affect other parts of the system?

### Edit:

A huge part of my problem is that gives a could not Import Module django error when just trying to python3 manage.py runserver, and django was indeed installed via pip-python3

 Also if i add the above (sys.path.append....) it does fix the django module problem but I shouldn't have to do this, I'm just not sure what the problem is

Comment: Shouldn't the appropriate directory already be on the path by default? Are you sure you're installing to the right place?

Comment: Bengt i have already looked through there, it doesn't answer my question

Comment: How did you install python3?

Comment: it comes pre-installed with fedora 20